JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter видит все запросы
Должен ли мой класс JwtAuthenticationFilter видеть все запросы если они .permitAll() -
JwtAuthenticationFilter
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    private final JwtTokenProvider tokenProvider;
    private final UserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                                    HttpServletResponse response,
                                    FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String token = getJWTfromRequest(request);
        if (token == null) {
            token = request.getParameter("token");
        }

        if (StringUtils.hasText(token) && tokenProvider.validateToken(token)) {
            String username = tokenProvider.getUsernameFromJWT(token);
            UserDetails userDetails = customUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);

            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities()
            );

            authenticationToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticationToken);

        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid or missing token for request");
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    public String getJWTfromRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String bearerToken = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        if (StringUtils.hasText(bearerToken) && bearerToken.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            return bearerToken.substring(7, bearerToken.length());
        }
        return null;
    }
}

JwtTokenProvider
@Component
public class JwtTokenProvider {

    @Value("${app.jwt-secret}")
    private String jwtSecret;

    @Value("${app.jwt-expiration-milliseconds}")
    private int jwtExpirationInMs = 30;

    public String generateToken(Authentication authentication) {
        String username = authentication.getName();
        Date currentDate = new Date();
        Date expireDate = new Date(currentDate.getTime() + jwtExpirationInMs);

        return Jwts.builder()
                .setSubject(username)
                .setIssuedAt(new Date())
                .setExpiration(expireDate)
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, jwtSecret)
                .compact();
    }

    public String getUsernameFromJWT(String token){
        Claims claims = Jwts.parser()
                .setSigningKey(jwtSecret)
                .build()
                .parseClaimsJws(token)
                .getBody();
        return claims.getSubject();
    }

    public boolean validateToken(String token) {
        System.out.println("validateToken - " + token);
        try {
            System.out.println("validateToken is valid");
            Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(jwtSecret).build().parseClaimsJws(token);
            return true;
        } catch (SignatureException ex) {
            throw new ApiException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "Invalid JWT signature");
        } catch (MalformedJwtException ex) {
            throw new ApiException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "Invalid JWT token");
        } catch (ExpiredJwtException ex) {
            throw new ApiException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "Expired JWT token");
        } catch (UnsupportedJwtException ex) {
            throw new ApiException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "Unsupported JWT token");
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            throw new ApiException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "JWT claims string is empty.");
        }
    }

}

SecurityConfig
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final JwtTokenProvider tokenProvider;
    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    private final UserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter(){
        return new JwtAuthenticationFilter(tokenProvider, customUserDetailsService);
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http, AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) throws Exception {
        return http
                .cors(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorizeRequests -> authorizeRequests
                        .requestMatchers("/", "/api/v1/auth/**").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .headers(httpSecurityHeadersConfigurer -> httpSecurityHeadersConfigurer.frameOptions(HeadersConfigurer.FrameOptionsConfig::disable))
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(HttpSecurity http, BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder) throws Exception {
        AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder = http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class);
        authenticationManagerBuilder
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
        return authenticationManagerBuilder.build();
    }
}

UserDetailsServiceImpl
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Service
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {
    private final UserRepository usersRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userNameOrEmail) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        boolean accountNonExpired = true;
        boolean credentialsNonExpired = true;
        boolean accountNonLocked = true;
        User user = usersRepository.findByEmailOrName(userNameOrEmail, userNameOrEmail).orElseThrow(() ->
                new UsernameNotFoundException("Не найден пользователь с таким именем или email: " + userNameOrEmail));

        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
                user.getEmail(),
                user.getPassword(),
                user.isEnabled(),
                accountNonExpired,
                credentialsNonExpired,
                accountNonLocked,
                getAuthorities(user));
    }

    private static Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(User user) {
        String[] userRoles = user.getRoles().stream()
                .map(Role::getName)
                .map(s -> "ROLE_" + s)
                .toArray(String[]::new);
        return AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList(userRoles);
    }
}

MainController
@Controller
public class MainController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String getHome() {
        return "home";
    }

    @GetMapping("/auth")
    public String getAuthPage() {
        return "auth";
    }

}

pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.dayzwiki</groupId>
    <artifactId>dayz-wiki</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>dayz-wiki</name>
    <description>online guide to the game Dayz</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.12.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <version>0.12.5</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>0.12.5</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-authorization-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>


Я нашел решения в виде метода shouldNotFilter который можно переопределить  -
@Override
protected boolean shouldNotFilter(HttpServletRequest request) throws ServletException {
String path = request.getRequestURI();
return PUBLIC_URLS.stream().anyMatch(path::equalsIgnoreCase);
}
и тогда у меня нету проблем он пропускает те запросы который я написал в PUBLIC_URLS но можно ли сделать это более лучше?
